# Microsoft Excel Undo Only Works Twice

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel-2003, undo

I am using Microsoft Excel 2003. A major irritant is that I am unable to use "undo" more than twice. Can you not use Undo more than 2 or 3 times or am I missing something? Are there any solutions to undoing more in Excel?

Comment: Office undo is horrendously inconsistent. You save and it'll clear the undo queue. WHY!?

Comment: I agree that this is annoying, however saving is sort of like saying, everything is correct, continue from here and only here... however this is no longer the case in 2007

Answer (score 2):

[From Microsoft Knowledge base article 211922](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/211922)

1. Close any programs that are running.
2. Click Start, click Run, type regedit in the Open box, and then click OK.
3. In Registry Editor, expand one of the following registry subkeys, as appropriate for the version of Excel that you are running:

   ```
   Microsoft Office Excel 2007
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Excel\Options

   Microsoft Office Excel 2003
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\11.0\Excel\Options

   Microsoft Excel 2002
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\10.0\Excel\Options

   Microsoft Excel 2000
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\9.0\Excel\Options
   ```
4. On the Edit menu, point to New, and then click DWORD Value. Select New Value #1, type UndoHistory, and then press ENTER.
5. On the Edit menu, click Modify.
6. In the Edit DWORD Value dialog box, click Decimal under Base. Type a value between 0 and 100 in the Value box, click OK, and then exit Registry Editor.
7. Start Excel. Excel stores an undo history for the number of actions that you specified in step 6.

Comment: My god, that is the most un-user-friendly way to change the number of undos ever conceived.  What maniac thought that one up?

Comment: Rather what maniac set the undo level at two and forgot to add a GUI option to change it.

Comment: I could swear I used to undo more than two at once - but been ages since I used 2003, so can't really comment.

Comment: The knowledge base article cited notes that the default is 16 levels. And yes it should be an easily changed configuration option.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Excel (2007) only allows undo twice *while still editing a cell* -- it's then basically toggling between the last edit and the previous cell contents. Going out of edit mode allows for normal undo behavior.

(I've sometimes experienced that undo applies to all open workbooks: change file A, change file B, change file A again, and then undo twice while file A is active: the last change in A and B are reverted, *not* the two changes in A.)